# how to insert data into two autocomplete textboxes

Tags: selenium, webdriver

my problem is i have two auto complete textboxes I have to enter value in first textbox it will be available upto enter value into second textbox when ever second textbox value is set the first text box value is unavailble my code is:

```
ap=new FirefoxDriver();
```

### first autocompletetextbox

```
ap.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='stationFrom']")).sendKeys("SECUNDERABAD JN (SC)");
```

### second auto complete textbox

```
ap.findElement(By.cssSelector("#stationTo")).sendKeys("GUNTUR JN (GNT)");
```

Comment: can you let us know what exactly the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

If it is automatically showing the data as you start type then use the below

first clear the text box using .clear command
second enter the data using .sendkeys command
use Thread.sleep
select the name which is shown as you type 
use thread.sleep

Do the above steps for both of the text boxes .